# Why ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError occur if change variable in ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider this code in [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/crs73tm21qBUkqpUlcXS?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  //changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    {{name}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  from: any;
  name: string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = '1'
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.name = "2"
  }
}
```

The above runs into `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error.

I have a couple question

1. Why is the error happening
2. Does this mean that `ngAfterViewInit` is not within the digest cycle?
3. Do we know what is the last hook that is within the digest cycle?

Comment: 1) The error is happening because Expression Change After Has Been Checked 2) Angular runs second change detection cycle in dev mode 3) The best way to know it is to open chrome dev tools and debug all cycle

Comment: @yurzui but why is `ngAfterViewInit` not in the first cycle, but in the second cycle?

Comment: first comes OnInit (when the value should be set) setting up the sources, then the children get checked (OnContentInit/Checked), then the host component does (AfterViewInit/Checked) in its full glory, knowing the size of the children etc. All of them have their reason to exist